# PHP - can not connect to remote mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache, vps

I have a problem connecting to my mysql database on another server from my VPS, connecting to localhost mysql works fine. This is my PHP script:

```
<?php
$servername = "mysql.example.com";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=database", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

I am getting this error: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'username'@'fh24-219.cybersales.cz' (using password: YES)`

The problem is propably that host changed from `mysql.example.com` to `fh24-219.cybersales.cz`(it points to my VPS ip). I have no idea why. I have already changed `httpd_can_network_connect_db` and `httpd_can_network_connect` to `1`. I would appreciate some help. I can connect to `mysql.example.com` with phpmyadmin. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds more like an IT support call issue with your server guys. Did you try asking them?

Comment: @Randall not yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible, that your `$username` do not have permissions to connect to database from server, where the PHP script is executed.

Try to create a user with permission to connect from remote server. Execute on MySQL server:

```
CREATE USER 'testuser'@'fh24-219.cybersales.cz' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

Change `'fh24-219.cybersales.cz'` to PHP server IP. If you will write `'%'` as server IP it will be accessible from anywhere (it is not recommended).

Updated:

If you do not know what permissions user have, execute `SHOW GRANTS;` on for e.g. PhpMyAdmin to see if remote IP is mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have acess to only one user, which doesn't have enough privilages to create new user. Do you think that my database hosting disabled remte acess to my database?

Comment: Connect to database with PhpMyAdmin and execute: SHOW GRANTS;
What hosts are mentioned for user?

Comment: Only localhost was mentioned. Thanks for your help, I've transfered database to my vps.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem, try changing the connection from:

```
new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=database", $username, $password);
```

to

```
new PDO("mysql: host=$servername;dbname=database", $username, $password);
```

Note the space between mysql: and host. It worked for me, can't guarantee you will not get access denied on the @localhost version of the account (I am stuck at this point) but it removes the trailing bit.

Comment: This doesn't work and also lacks any explanation or logic. Please try to post logical explanations